# Copying Cassandra data from one cluster to another

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster setup in Cassandra on AWS. Now, I need to move my cluster to some other place. Since taking image is not possible, I will create a new cluster exactly a replica of the old one. Now I need to move the data from this cluster to another. How can I do so?

My cluster has 2 data centers and each data center has 3 Cassandra machines with 1 seed machine.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have connectivity between the old and new cluster? If yes, why not linking the cluster and let cassandra replicate the data to the new cluster? After data is transferred, shut down the old cluster. Ideally you wouldn`t even have any downtime.

Comment: How stupid I am, Thank you. This could have struck me earlier.

Comment: Slight problem. Since I have to move from one VPC to another in AWS, I cannot have connection between old and new cluster. Is there any other option apart from this?

Comment: It should be possible to configure your vpc network configurations in a way that the vpc is accessable from the internet. If this is done for both of your vpc`s, cassandra should be able to connect between them. I have not tried this in AWS, but from the description of AWS this should be easily possible: https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/

Answer (score 0):

You can take your SSTables from your data directory and then can use sstableloader in new data center to import the data.

Before doing this activity you might consider doing compaction so that you have only one SSTable per table.

[SSTable Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using SFTP server or through some other way, transfer the SSTables from old cluster to new cluster (one DC is enough) and use SSTableLoader. The data replication to another DC will be taken care by Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra there are two type of strategy **SimpleStrategy** and **NetworkTopologyStrategy by** using NetworkTopologyStrategy you can replicate in different cluster. see this documentation [Data replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html)

You can use COPY command to export and import csv from one table to another
[Simple data importing and exporting with Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra)